# How can I edit object members in a priority queue once it has been pushed onto the queue

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I'm still new to C++. I would like to modify the variable "change" once I have already pushed the struct A onto the priority queue. Can this be done?
This is what I have tried

```
pq.top().change = 200; //But it says this is only readable
```

This is the what I have:

```
priority_queue<A, vector<A>, comparator> pq;

struct A{
    vector<B> list;
    int change = 0;
};
```

Any guidence would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Is what you really want to do to change the order of things in the queue after they have been added to the queue?

Comment: top() returns an iterator, I think.  you will need to dereference.  try *pq.top...

Comment: The placement of an item in a priority queue is decided by its value. The safest, easiest way to update this position is to pop it off, change it, push it back in.

Comment: @ttemple You think wrong.

Comment: No, this is not what a priority queue is for. Whatever problem you're trying to solve with this, either it's the wrong solution, or a priority queue is the wrong container for this.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, you should always prefer to use `std::vector` unless you have severe cause to use something else. We can't see exactly what you are doing with your `priority_queue`, but it may be time to think "Is this the right tool for the job?"

Comment: @Tas Do you know if Heaps will allow you to edit an element once the Object has been inserted onto the heap? I ask this because I need a container with a comparator(i.e. priority queue).

Comment: Please avoid the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) and give us the big picture of what you're trying to do, besides the specific problem and what you're currently trying. I think you can actually update a value in a heap, but whatever you're trying to do, using standard library containers will be much easier than making your own heap.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I edit object members in a priority queue once it has been pushed onto the queue

You can not modify non-mutable members of an object within a priority queue, because `top` returns a const reference.

What you can do, is make a copy of the `top`, then `pop` it, and `push` the modified copy.

Or, you could use a mutable member, but if you do so, remember that `Compare` must not use that member.

Comment: Would I be able to insert a pointer for the priority queue and create another pointer pointing to the same data on the queue, so I can edit it outside the queue?

Comment: @JDoe4444 As long as you don't touch any data used by `Compare`, sure you could do that.